# Discrete Time-invariant System with Exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm looking for a solution of the following discrete-time system:

$x_{t + 1} = A \cdot x_t + B \cdot \exp (x_t) + c$,

where $x_t$ is $n$-dimensional vector, $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ constant matrices, and $c$ is $n$-dimensional constant vector. Also, $\exp(\cdot)$ is applied to $x_t$ in entry-wise manner.

I'm interested in finding $f$ such that for any $x_0, A, B, c$ and $t > 0$ it satisfies:

$x_t = f(x_0, A, B, c, t)$

Does the above system can be solved for a closed-form $f$? If so, how can I proceed in finding it?

If not, can it be solved under additional assumptions? For example, if I assume $A$ and $B$ being invertable matrices, would it allow for a closed-form solution? What about the case where $A$ is the identity?

Any suggestions?

Comment: No it can't be solved. Note that in the simplest case of $n=1$, you essentially have tetration-like growth, unless $B\le0$ or something. But even then, repeatedly applying $\exp$ does not have a closed form. So you can only tackle this for $B=0$.

Comment: In a problem for which I'm trying to solve this system, all the constant are such that $x_t$ is finite and $x_{\infty}$ converges to a specific finite vector. Under stability and convergence conditions can it be solved?

Comment: If not, is there an elegant proof that this system has no closed-form solution? Applying $\exp(\cdot)$ repeatedly seems like something we can't solve, but how such statement can be proved?